# Is $\psi(x)-\log x$ strictly increasing for strictly positive $x$?

Tags: digamma-function

Let $\psi(x)$ be the digamma function. Is the function which takes $\psi(x)-\log x$ for $x>0$ strictly increasing, and how could one show this if it is the case (link etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you allowed to use $\psi(z)
= -\gamma + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n + z}\right)$ ? If so $$\psi'(x)-\frac1x = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac1{(x+n)^2}-\int_{x+n}^{x+n+1} \frac1{t^2}dt$$

Comment: Yes, and thanks a lot for the answer and the editting :) Im not quite sure how to obtain the right hand side of $$\psi'(x)-\frac1x = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac1{(x+n)^2}-\int_{x+n}^{x+n+1} \frac1{t^2}dt$$ can you maybe elaborate on that?

Comment: What do you get when differientating $\psi(x)-\log x$

Comment: Okay sry for not writting what I had tried. Okay, so i guess the derivative of $\psi(x)-\log(x)$ is equal to $\psi'(x)-\frac{1}{x}$ which is the left hand side. Since $\psi(x)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+x}$ and the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+x)^2}$ is uniformly convergend for $x>0$ i also guess we also know that $\psi'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+x)^2}$. But then I guess I end up with $-\int_{x+n}^{x+n+1} \frac{1}{t^2}dt$ which i get to be $\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n+1)}$ should be equal to $1/x$? so i must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: $\sum_{n\ge 0}\int_{x+n}^{x+n+1} \frac1{t^2}dt = \int_x^\infty \frac1{t^2}dt$ @Mathisfun

Comment: Arhhh so the integral was inside the summation, thanks alot reuns :)